# Video picker using Photos framework

Tags: ios, swift, photosframework

I'm trying to pull all the videos in a user's library using the Photos framework and display them in a collection view. Basically implementing my own video picker.

I'm using PHCachingImageManager to start caching image thumbnails for each video. When 'cellForItemAt indexPath' gets called, I get 'unexpectedly found nil when unwrapping an Optional value' when I call PHCachingImageManager.requestImage(...) and trying to set my cell's image in the closure.

```
viewDidLoad() {
    // Register Cell classes
    self.collectionView!.register(PhotosCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    let videosAlbum = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: .smartAlbum, subtype: .smartAlbumVideos, options: nil)

    print(videosAlbum.count) // prints as 1 bc videosAlbum contains 1 collection
    self.videos = PHAsset.fetchAssets(in: videosAlbum.object(at: 0), options: nil)
    print(self.videos.count) // prints the # of videos in the Videos smart album

    self.imageManager.startCachingImages(for: self.videos.objects(at: [0, videos.count-1]), targetSize: CGSize(width: 150, height: 150), contentMode: .aspectFit, options: nil)
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! PhotosCell
    let asset = videos.object(at: indexPath.item)

    imageManager.requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: CGSize(width: 150, height: 150), contentMode: .aspectFill, options: nil, resultHandler: {
        image, _ in
                cell.thumbnailImage = image //this is the line throwing the error
    })
    return cell
}
```

Could this be a problem with the way I'm implementing my PhotosCell class? Or a problem with how I'm using 'collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(...)?

```
class PhotosCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var photoThumbnail: UIImageView!

var thumbnailImage: UIImage! {
    didSet {
        photoThumbnail.image = thumbnailImage
    }
}
}
```

I looked around and thought I saw where closures passed to the cache manager are put on a background thread, but that shouldn't affect the optional UIImageView.image being set on the line with the error, right?
The GitHub code is [here](https://github.com/areichle/iOS-Frameworks/tree/master/PhotosPicker) for more context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your self-answer fixed the problem without you being sure why, here's a fuller explanation...

When you set a prototype cell in the storyboard, it automatically registers that cell definition with the collection view, so you don't need to call `registerCellClass` or `registerNib`.

In fact, if you *do* call `registerCellClass`, `dequeueReusableCell` will try to create new cell instances using your cell class' default initializer (`init(frame:)` most likely). That means it won't load your cell class from the storyboard, so any `IBOutlet` connections you set up there won't be connected — so your cell's `photoThumbnail` outlet is nil, causing the trap you found.

So your self-answer is right — just don't call `registerCellClass` and let the storyboard handle it for you. (Behind the scenes, Xcode compiles your storyboard into multiple nibs, and the nib loading code calls `registerNib:forCellWithReuseIdentifier:` with the one you set as the prototype cell.)

---

While we're here, let's fix another possible problem in your code. Your `requestImage` completion handler doesn't execute until after `collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)` returns. This means that during or after scrolling, the cell you're setting an image on might have been reused — so it now represents a different indexPath than the one you requested an image for, and you're now setting the wrong image on it.

If you look in Apple's [Using Photos Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/samplecode/UsingPhotosFramework/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014575) sample code, they do some extra work to make sure that the asynchronous setting of images on cells works out right. In their `AssetGridViewController`:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let asset = fetchResult.object(at: indexPath.item)

    // Dequeue a GridViewCell.
    guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: String(describing: GridViewCell.self), for: indexPath) as? GridViewCell
        else { fatalError("unexpected cell in collection view") }

    // Request an image for the asset from the PHCachingImageManager.
    cell.representedAssetIdentifier = asset.localIdentifier
    imageManager.requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: thumbnailSize, contentMode: .aspectFill, options: nil, resultHandler: { image, _ in
        // The cell may have been recycled by the time this handler gets called;
        // set the cell's thumbnail image only if it's still showing the same asset.
        if cell.representedAssetIdentifier == asset.localIdentifier {
            cell.thumbnailImage = image
        }
    })
    return cell
}
```

Comment: So 'registerCellClass' is only used when setting up a cell within a collection view? And is there a reason this line is not included in the boiler plate code included in a table view? Just seems odd this gets included with a collection view but not tables.  Thank you for the lesson on the sample project. I had been going over that for awhile and took out the 'assetIdentifer' thinking that might've attributed to the problem. And is there a reason the sample cell uses setters instead of [cell].[outlet].image = [UIImage] ?

Comment: To answer your followup questions in order...`registerCellClass` is primarily for when you're setting up a collection view programmatically (as opposed to with storyboards or nibs).

Comment: Collection views are newer than table views, so they get some design patterns that reflect lessons Apple learned between iOS 2 and iOS 6. (And changes in underlying hardware performance.)

Comment: And probably whoever wrote that sample code thought it'd be good for the cell to abstract away how it presents its contents. If the cell has an image setter instead of directly exposing its image view, it can do something else with that image in the future, without code that calls the cell needing to change.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason by deleting the lines:

```
// Register Cell classes
self.collectionView!.register(PhotosCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
```

in the ViewDidLoad() method, it displays the thumbnails fine. Before, the cell wasn't being initialized (I assume), and it was throwing the error when trying to set the cell's UIImageView.image.

Not sure if this affects any other functionality of the UICollectionView though...

Comment: Well, what does `self.collectionView!.register(PhotosCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)` mean? It means, "Don't get this cell from the prototype cell in the storyboard." But you _do_ want to get this cell from the prototype cell in the storyboard. So clearly that was the wrong thing to say.